# Array Manipulation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array say

```
let array = [4,5,7,2,6,8,2,5,7,9,0,1,365,65,33,23,65]
```

Now when I write below code

```
let test = array.drop { (x) -> Bool in
    x < 10
}
```

the output is `array is : [365, 65, 33, 23, 65]`  which is true because we are dropping elements less than 10.

But what would be the case when want to drop all the elements which are greater than 10, so I wrote below code

```
let test = array.drop { (x) -> Bool in
    x > 10
}
```

Now output `array is : [4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 9, 0, 1, 365, 65, 33, 23, 65]`

Can anyone explain why this behaviour? Please help what am I missing in above code? I am using Swift 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drop` function is actually `drop(while:)`

The condition `x > 10` is evaluated for the while-loop, in your case, the number 4, since the condition is not met, we exit the `drop` function.

From your first example using `x < 10`, you got lucky because all values smaller than 10 are all on the left side of the array, so it worked, but it `365` was the first element, you will get the same result as your second case, it will exit the while-loop after evaluating the first element.

I would suggest to use the `filter` method instead:

```
let test = array.filter { (x) -> Bool in
            return x < 10
           }
// or shorthand expression
let test = array.filter({$0 < 10})

// array is
[4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 9, 0, 1]
```

For reference: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2830228-drop

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `filter`, not `drop`.

From the documentation for `drop(where:)`:

> Returns a subsequence by skipping elements while predicate returns true and returning the remaining elements.

So as soon as the condition in the `drop` block is false, the rest of the array is returned.

Your first test case seemed to work because all of the values < 10 happen to be before any values > 10.

Here's the proper solution using `filter`:

```
let array = [4,5,7,2,6,8,2,5,7,9,0,1,365,65,33,23,65]
let test = array.filter { $0 < 10 }
print(test)
```

> [4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 9, 0, 1]

```
let array = [4,5,7,2,6,8,2,5,7,9,0,1,365,65,33,23,65]
let test = array.filter { $0 > 10 }
print(test)
```

> [365, 65, 33, 23, 65]

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2830228-drop) states:

> **drop(while:)**
>
> Returns a subsequence by skipping elements while predicate returns
>   true and returning the remaining elements.

So what happens is, when the closure returns `false`, it stops skipping the elements.

What you are doing seems to be a job for the [filter(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/lazymapiterator/1688489-filter) function.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not working as it returns false and breaks the very first time it encounters a value less than 10.

But the first sequence works till the numbers are less than 10. So if you insert a number less than between greater than 10 numbers it wont be removed.

So for your array  `let array = [4,5,7,2,6,8,2,5,7,9,0,1,365,65,33,23,65]`
if you insert 13 after 65 or 365, it will not be removed.

Since your array starts from a number less than 10 it evaluates the value and returns false since its smaller and the loop breaks, thus removing none for condition > 10.

The result you want can be achieved using  `filter`

.